# Restrict Categories to Editor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making a Complaint Management System using Quality Control Theme in Wordpress. I want to have a super admin, admins and users in it. The admins will be basically admins for a particular category so that they only view, edit and change the complaints in that category.

I used User Assign Categories Plugin to do so. The admin panel for admins worked fine i.e. I can only edit and change the posts of particular category. But on the website the admin can see all the complaints and even edit them. I want to restrict the admin to view only the complaints under his category on website too. I tried a hell lot of plugins to do that but no success. Please help me. (I assigned the admins the role of editor)

Comment: You'll probably need to write you own solution. I don't have any snippet for this, but I know that `pre_get_posts` can be used for that. Search for it at [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bpre_get_posts+%2Bcurrent_user_can).

Comment: Thanks...I finally wrote the snippet to do so.

Comment: Would be nice if you shared the solution as an Answer.